# Conditions for Coercivity Condition

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization, banach-spaces, nonlinear-optimization, coercive

Let $\ell^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the Banach space of sequences in $\mathbb{R}^d$ for which the norm $\|(x_n)_n\|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \|x_n\|_2$ is finite.  Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be non-constant, lower semi-continuous, and coercive.  So it admits a minimizer by Tonelli's direct method.

---

Under what additional (growth?) conditions on $f$ can I guarantee that there is a sequence (of sequences) $\{(x_n^N)_n\}_N$ in $\ell^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, such that $x_n^N=0$ for every $n>N$ and the the coercivity-type condition is satisfied:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N f(x_n^N) = \inf_{(y_n)_n\in \ell^1(\mathbb{R}^n)} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(y_n) + \mathscr{o}(1) \mbox{ as } N\to \infty.
$$

---

**Update:**  I managed to show that it is enough for the map $x_n\mapsto \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x_n)$ to have compact sub-level sets...and by Grothendieck's result this means that the set
$$
\left\{
(y_n)_n \in \ell^1(\mathbb{R}^d):\, 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(y_n)\leq s
\right\}\subseteq \overline{co\left(
\{(z_n)_n\}_{N \in \mathbb{N}}
\right)},
$$
where $\|(z_n^N)\|_{\ell^1(\mathbb{R}^d)}\to 0$ as $N\to \infty$.  However, I cannot manage to relate this condition to $f$..

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: My intuition said that $f$ should be super-quadratic, so I've been trying to show that in that case, the level-sets are of $(x_n)_n\mapsto \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(x_n)$ are compact.. so we get this condition...but I can't manage to get anywhere.

Comment: Yeah that looks tough. Compactness is pretty hard to come by in infinite-dimensional spaces. On the bright side, I believe we get closedness of the lower-level sets for free, since $f$ is lsc.

Comment: The most I've seen (in a book) about coercivity conditions (and more generally, sufficient conditions for existence results in this sort of problem) -- is in *Asymptotic Cones and Functions in Optimization and Variational Inequalities* by Auslender and Teboulle, 2002. Hopefully something there may help you out.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look this one up :)